# how to understand a sentence composed of a bunch of nouns+propositions + participles without a main verb?

Tags: sentence-meaning

> Figures 1 and 2 show, for each of 6 of the isotopes listed in Table 1, **the change over time in the number of the nuclei remaining, N, in a sample initially containing 1,000 of the nuclei.**(From ACT)

What does the bold text mean? I don't think there is a predicate/main verb for the sentence, and the meaning is just elusive to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The skeleton of the sentence (basic structure) is

> [Figures 1 and 2] [**show**] [the change [over time [in the number of the nuclei remaining, N, [in a sample initially containing 1,000 of the nuclei]]].

where "figure 1 and 2" is the subject, "show" the main verb, and ["the change" + PP complement] the object.

Comment: Could you further explain what come after "the change"? A whole bunch of preposition phrases...

Comment: The direct object is actually the long noun phrase "the change over time in the number of the nuclei remaining, N, in a sample initially containing 1,000 of the nuclei". The expression "over time in the number of the nuclei remaining, N, in a sample initially containing 1,000 of the nuclei" is a preposition phrase modifying "change” and within that PP is the further PP “in the number of the nuclei remaining, N, in a sample initially containing 1,000 of the nuclei" and a further PP “in a sample initially containing 1,000 of the nuclei.

Comment: @Charlie Please see the updated answer